# Arcgis Javascript API WMTS Layer don't use the configured proxy

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, proxy, wmts

I am new about Arcgis javascript API. I'm using WMTSLayer and i have configured to use a proxy.

```
esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = <Proxy_url>
```

When the API does the GetCapabilities request, the request goes through the proxy. But tiles requests does not use the proxy.

This is the expected result? What can i do to force the tiles request to use the proxy configuration?

Comment: Why do you need to go via the proxy for the tiles? The only reason I can think of is the server is in a DMZ and the client does not have access to the tile source server.

Comment: @kes Exactly. Or vice-versa, the client is in a secured environment and the server is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected result - the getCapabilities request goes via the proxy as it could be prevented by the browser as a [Cross Origin Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

As the tiles themselves are loaded as images these are permitted cross-origin and so don't need to be loaded via the proxy - this can't be forced by configuring the Javascript API.

If you needed to force the tile requests to go via the proxy, you could do so by creating a new layer type and override the [getTileUrl](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/tiledmapservicelayer-amd.html#gettileurl) method.

A better solution though would be to resolve the issue with the mapservice that is requiring you to go via the proxy for the tiles, for example by enabling direct access to the tile server from the client.